# Continuous numbers based on value of a next column

Tags: excel, vba

I manage to amend a code that I found to suits my needs but I can't figure it out how to do the last important part.

Column E are the orders and H are suppliers
[image: Column E are the orders and H are suppliers]

I'm trying automatically to create NEXT number for the next supplier. (they should look the same as the picture, without the first one is it is part of the problem).

On my current code when I press on E10 (empty cell) will generate the numbers for each supplier.

The problem is that the code is not starting from my current cell (empty one) and transform every cell in the column after row 3. I presume this is because of `For i = 3 To N`. But I need to be from any cell that is next and leave the previous cells alone.

```
Sub FillA()
    Dim SeqNum As Long, iNum As Long
    Dim N As Long, i As Long
   
    
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

last4 = Right(ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 0).Value, 4)

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    SeqNum = last4
    iNum = 1
    ActiveCell.Value = ActiveCell.Value & Format(SeqNum + iNum)
    N = Cells(Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp).Row

   For i = 3 To N
        If Cells(i, "H").Value = Cells(i - 1, "H").Value Then
            iNum = iNum
            Cells(i, "E").Value = "PAU2100" & Format(SeqNum + iNum)
        End If

        If Cells(i, "H").Value <> Cells(i - 1, "H").Value Then
            iNum = iNum + 1
            SeqNum = SeqNum
            Cells(i, "E").Value = "PAU2100" & Format(SeqNum + iNum)
            End If
            
             If Cells(i + 1, "H").Value = 0 Then
          Exit Sub
         
    
        End If
        Next i
        

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure about all of this, but based on your example, this should replicate the results you have shown.   It works off the activecell when you run it

```
Sub FillA()
    Dim SeqNum As Long, iNum As Long
    Dim N, r As Long, i As Long
   
    
Application.ScreenUpdating = False


    iNum = 1
    r = ActiveCell.Row   'So it will start on the row you choose
    N = Cells(Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp).Row

   For i = r To N
   'Checks to see if there is an order number in the above row
        If Left(Cells(i - 1, "E").Value, 7) <> "PAU2100" Then
        'You will need to make a decision if it's the first row of data
        ' or the order number doesn't start with PAU2100
            Cells(i, "E").Value = "PAU21001265"
        
   'Checks to see if the suppliers are the same
        ElseIf Cells(i, "H").Value = Cells(i - 1, "H").Value Then
               Cells(i, "E").Value = Cells(i - 1, "E").Value

     'Checks to see if the suppliers are the different
        ElseIf Cells(i, "H").Value <> Cells(i - 1, "H").Value Then
                SeqNum = Right(Cells(i - 1, "E").Value, 4)
            Cells(i, "E").Value = "PAU2100" & Format(SeqNum + iNum)
        End If
    ' this will only trigger if you have blanks in your supplier data
          If Cells(i + 1, "H").Value = 0 Then
          Exit Sub
         
    
        End If
        Next i
 
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
       

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for the notes too as I am new to VBA and I am trying to understand how the code works.